# How to convert HTML chars in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Developing PHP application that generates Excel documents on the fly, using PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

Problem I have is that my Excel document will contain some special HTML chars, like `&deg;`, `&rsquo;`, `&rdquo;` etc...

But in generated XLS file, all I getting is `&deg;`, `&rsquo;`, `&rdquo;`, etc, not °, ’, ”, like I need.

Can you help me how to get this in XLS documents?

Comment: Can't you just [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) the string before you use it in the Excel sheet? Or does this not work for some reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember that you should always use UTF-8 for strings in PHPExcel

```
$str = '32&deg;Fahrenheit = 0&deg;Centigrade';
$str = html_entity_decode($str,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```