# PHPExcel writing issue

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpexcel

I need to write a .xls file with data from mysql database. Everything is fine, except when there's a field with this string: "FALSE N¦ DO NOT USE".

In this case, in the specific cell it writes only "FALSE N" and it stops there, without writing "¦" and everything that comes after.

This issues come also with other characters such as "Ï"

This is the piece of code that writes the file.

```
while (!$rs->EOF){  
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValueExplicit('A'.$i, $rs->fields["nr_id"], PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING2)
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $rs->fields["descrizione"]) //this is the field that gives me the problem
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, number_format($rs->fields["prezzo_eur"], 2, ",", ""));
$rs->Movenext();
$i++;
}
```

Is there a way to just write everything?

It does nothing to do with html entities!

UPDATE: i just encoded in utf8 and everything is fine, thanks to everybody!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610697/how-to-convert-html-chars-in-phpexcel

Comment: Ensure that all string you store in cells are UTF-8

Comment: Yeah Mark, that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) and by the author of the question, the solution is:

> Ensure that all string you store in cells are UTF-8